# Magento - Display different text for different customer groups (depending)

Tags: php

I have a magento store with seven different customer groups. My goal is to display a little text - depending on the customer group - under the price at the product page  (price.phtml).

Customer Groups:
Group0 and Group1 need one text (ex. text for Group01)
Group2, Group3 and Group 4 need their own text (ex. text for Group234)
Group5, Group6 and Group 7 also need their own text (ex. text for Group567)

So far I have got this working for one customer group:

```
<?php       
    $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
    if($_isLoggedIn == true){
    $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
    if($_myGroupId == 1){
    ?> <br/><span class="price_text"><?php echo $this->__("ex. text for Group01") ?></span>
    <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Now my problem is to change the function to an if-elseif-else... can anyone help me complete this function?

Thank you very much in advance
Tina

Answer (score 1):

you can do the quick and dirty way and just have a switch-case for each customer group.
Something like this:

```
switch ($_myGroupId) {
   case 1:
     echo "TEXT for group 1 here";
     break
   case 2: 
     echo "TEXT for group 2 here";
     break;
   ....
}
```

But this falls over when you have to add an other group.
Here is how I would do it. 
I would create a system->config section where you get a textarea for each customer group and you use that textarea to fill in the text you need.

Here is a tutorial to create [such a section](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2013/02/create-system-config-section-with.html).
Using this, each time you add a new customer group a new textarea will be added so you don't have to code anything.
Then just do this in your template:

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('section_name/group_name/group_'.$_myGroupId);?>
```